# Oracle forms 10g - Private packages

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-apps

While reading Oracle Applications Developer’s Guide,  I came across these lines-

If a client–side (Oracle Forms) package exceeds the 10K limit, you can reduce the size of the package by putting private variables and procedures in one or more
”private packages.”

could someone explain how to create private packages?
Any helpful links is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no private packages as such in oracle,but you can have use private procedures or functions inside a package which are accessible only to the package.

Procedures and Functions inside a package can be made private by not declaring them in the package specifications

Another point to note is that private procedures or functions can be called only inside the package body and we should declare them before they are called

In your case to solve 10k Limit issue you can define a wrapper package and them call a package where you can define a public procedure which you define in the package specifications and body and pass all the arguments and use the public procedure to only call the private procedure

you can refer the answer in the below for example

[Execute private procedure globally in oracle package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924490/how-do-i-execute-private-procedures-in-an-oracle-package)

Wrapper package

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY testPackage_Wrapper AS
 PROCEDURE publicProc IS
 BEGIN
 testPackage.publicProc();
 END;
```

Comment: In that documentation they have given that even package body is not allowed to hold more than 10K. so go for private packages. I know how to create private procedures to chunk the size of a procedure. But how to limit the size of a package (using private packages) is the thing i want to know. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: It is troublesome but you can just try using a wrapper package to call the public procedures in package which calls private procedures or functions

Comment: included the wrapper package in answer